# How to use OpenCV VideoWriter on Mac

Tags: macos, opencv, video, avi

I have the following code which writes a few frames to a .avi video file. This works perfectly fine on a windows machine but when I try it on my Mac it creates the .avi file and displays no errors, but the file will not play. I haven't been able to find a clear solution so far.
I am currently using Mac OSX 10.9.2.

```
void videoWriter()
{
    CvVideoWriter *writer;
    writer = cvCreateVideoWriter("test.avi",CV_FOURCC('I','Y','U','V'),1,Size(640,480),1);

    for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    {
        if(imMan.returnSelect(i)) {
            cout << "Frame " << i << endl;
            /****** Original Image *********/
            Mat frame = imMan.returnOrg(i);
            IplImage fr = frame;
            cvWriteFrame(writer,&fr);
        }
    }

    cvReleaseVideoWriter(&writer);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

what is the size of `frame`?

In my experience, `cvWriteFrame` will not generate error even if the 4th parameter of `cvCreateVideoWriter` does not match with the dimension of your image frame. And it write something like an header. (with 414 byte...)

make sure they match exactly.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the right combination of codec and extension.

The codec is platform dependent. That could be the problem.

Try using this combination:

`writer = cvCreateVideoWriter("test.mkv",CV_FOURCC(*'X264),1,Size(640,480),1);`

Here is the reference [link](https://docs.opencv.org/master/dd/d43/tutorial_py_video_display.html)